# Networking issue solved by changing VMs MAC address of VM but the root cause of the issue is still a mystery

Tags: linux, networking, macos, virtualbox

I have a Linux VirtualBox VM on a MacBook Air that connects to the internet via USB ethernet cable.

The Linux VM uses a bridged adapter that I switch between wifi and wired usb, depending on my location and it's connection method.

The Linux VM also uses `git` to [reconfigure the vm's network configuration](http://leeand00.tiddlyspot.com/#%5B%5BSetting%20up%20a%20mobile-mobile%20development%20environment%20in%20linux%20with%20GIT%20and%20DNSMasq%5D%5D) based on the requirements of the particular network it is connecting to.  When connecting at home on my wifi network the vm would connect just fine.

My office has two connection methods, private wifi and wired.

The wifi would connect, and access the internet alright, but it seemed like the webpages would load slow like they were being loaded on a single connection.  And when using SSH to a remote machine the typing of characters would stall.  So I tried using the wired internet instead.

I switched the bridged connection in Virtual Box so that it would point to the wired connection, and then switched the git [configuration](http://leeand00.tiddlyspot.com/#%5B%5BSetting%20up%20a%20mobile-mobile%20development%20environment%20in%20linux%20with%20GIT%20and%20DNSMasq%5D%5D)  so that it's `interface` reflected a static ip allowed to occur on the wired network.

At this point I could only ping machines inside my own network, and intermittently I could ping 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS), but after a while it would stop working.

The way that I fixed this was to change the mac address of the nic, and adjust accordingly in my Debian based distro by deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and rebooting first.

Is it possible that the network knew the same mac address was being used for the wifi and the wired network, and therefore booted off the connection? (we have Sonicwalls at work).

Or did something else cause the problem?

Comment: It was a gu-gu-gu-ghost!

Comment: I'm sorry is this not the correct exchange to be asking this question in?

Comment: You're asking us to guess why something was wrong, when the reasons offered (if any) can't be verified (unless you're willing to break it again and test theories and answers as they come in).   Therefore it's an unanswerable question that will garner only guesses and opinion (IMO).  Yes, the Sonicwalls could possibly be doing this, as could many other network security devices, none of which do we know how it's configured.

Comment: Since you seem to suspect the Sonicwalls, and we can't possible know how they're configured without you telling us, have you checked their setup to ensure they're not enforcing MAC addresses?  How another other network devices you may have?  Anyhow, keep in mind, it takes more than one vote to close. :)

Comment: Well I can ask someone to check that if they are enforcing that.

Comment: It just did it again, and about a minute later I could access computers outside the network again.

Comment: Then I'd say edit your original question, explaining the problem you're facing in the context that it's NOT fixed, and include what you've tried and what the results were.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would forget about *git* completely, and would try to connect the good old-fashioned way: by hand. Try this, and tell us whether this works:

1.Pick bridge adapter on ethernet connection.

2.In the VM, stop *git* and network-manager, if you have it:

```
 sudo service network-manager stop
```

3.reset your VM's ethernet NIC:

```
 sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

4.Now try to connect manually:

```
 sudo ifconfig eth0 up

 sudo dhclient -v eth0
```

and see whether you connect. If you do, *i.e.*, if you see an offer of an IP address, then please add these two lines by hand to your /etc/resolv.conf file,

```
 nameserver 8.8.4.4

 nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

then try to ping the DNSs:

```
  ping -c3 8.8.4.4
```

If all of this works, then anything untoward is the responsibility of your firm's firewall and/or proxy  settings. If it does not work, please let us know here what fails and, above all, **exactly how** it does fail.

Comment: I just use git to write out my configuration files, for `/etc/network/interfaces` and `dnsmasq.conf` so I can switch between networks easily; when I have a working configuration for a network, I add it to a branch in `git` and load it back up when I return to the same network.  Thanks but I already know how to do that stuff.

Comment: @leeand00 The point is not teaching you how to do this, the point is prompting you to do this, to separate clearly issues related to your pc from issues related to the management of your LAN. I am under the impression other skillful readers have already prompted you to clarify your question.

Comment: Alright I sent the place that manages our lan an email we'll see what they say...